# How to filter a list of a class by a list of a string?

Tags: c#, linq, filter

So I have this class:

```
class Blah
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Blah(string nums, string ttls)
    {
        Number = nums;
        Title = ttls;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to filter it by list of numbers (which are strings).

So I would like to do something like this:

```
List<Blah> blahs = new List<Blah> {Blah("0233", "Ho"), Blah("1209", "Ah"), Blah("2929", "Eh")};

List<string> bleh = new List<string> {"10233", "21209"};

List<Blah> missBlahs = (blahs.Where(b => !bleh.Contains(b.Number))).ToList<Blah>();

//Result: Blah("2929", "Eh")
```

However, I keep getting the whole list of blahs back. Which I don't want.

Comment: Your example lists don't intersect (i.e. no entry in `blahs` has a `Number` within the list `bleh`). Was that intentional?

Comment: That's because you check whether the collection `[10233, 21209]` contains `0233` and `1209`. Which it doesn't, so these aren't filtered. You have to add an aditional layer which checks it for each entry of the collection.

Comment: You need to explain why the numbers in `bleh` are prefixed with their index (`1xxx, 2xxx`), and what logic this index implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting to filter out any `Number` property which is a substring of any value in the `List<String>`?  Given that none of the values directly match this appears to be the case.  If so then try the following

```
blahs
  .Where(b => bleh.Any(x => x.Contains(b.Number))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to be it. Let's me do some double-checking, first.

Comment: Works as advertised! Thank you, sir!

Comment: @dotNetN00b It works until your `bleh` contains something like `ixyz`, where `ixy` is what is being searched and the actual value in `bleh` would be `xyz`. According to your example input, you want to ignore `i`, causing those to not match, while they will be matching according to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first digits in the bleh List are typos, this does what you want

```
List<Blah> blahs = new List<Blah> { new Blah("0233", "Ho"), new Blah("1209", "Ah"), new Blah("2929", "Eh") };

List<string> bleh = new List<string> { "0233", "1209" };

List<Blah> missedBlahs = blahs.FindAll(b => !bleh.Contains(b.Number));

//Result: Blah("2929", "Eh")
```

Comment: In the "bleh" list, I removed "1" from "10233" and "2 from "21209". If you want them in there, you're probably looking at a Regex